# Azure - Windows Azure Virtual Machine Issue

Tags: azure

I had a virtual machine fail, is there anyway to figure out why the machine became unresponsive? I have no way of connecting to the VM, as RDP does not appear to be responding. What are the options in this case, and or preventative measures that can be put in place to prevent this from happening in the future?

Thanks,

Steve Armitage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in a situation like this there's not much you can do but contact [Microsoft Support](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/).  I've always found them helpful, but you do need to be aware that root cause analysis of a problem can sometimes take a while.  As far as preventing this problem from happening again, that depends on the problem.  I've encountered two such cases, once it was because of a memory leak in our code so it was something I could fix, the other it was something only MS could fix so it's hard to say.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft Support for VM's hosted in Azure is non-existent. Their suggestion was to post here. As the Windows Azure team is monitoring this site.

Comment: I should have thought of that, I think VMs are still in preview and there's no official support for products in preview.